# Android progress bar for method

Tags: android, methods, android-progressbar

I have a custom method of my class that (on my Android phone) takes 2-3 second to finish, and I would like to surround it with a progress bar.

Here is my method:

```
public void getQuestionsForSelectedCategory(){
    ArrayList<Question> temp = (ArrayList<Question>) this.clone();
    ArrayList<Question> tempGroup;
    this.clear();
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
        tempGroup = new ArrayList<Question>();
        for(int j=0;j<temp.size();j++)
            if((temp.get(j).getGroup()==i+1)&&(temp.get(j).getCategory().contains(category)||temp.get(j).getCategory().equals("*")))
                tempGroup.add(temp.get(j));
        getQuestionsForSelectedGroup(tempGroup, numbersByGroup[i], pointsByGroup[i]);
    }

    tempGroup = new ArrayList<Question>();
    for(int i=0;i<temp.size();i++){
        int a = temp.get(i).getGroup();
        if((a==3||a==4||a==5||a==6||a==7))
            if(temp.get(i).getCategory().contains(category)||temp.get(i).getCategory().equals("*"))
                tempGroup.add(temp.get(i));
    }
    Collections.shuffle(tempGroup);
    getQuestionsForSelectedGroup(tempGroup, numbersByGroup[2], pointsByGroup[2]);

    if(category.equals("C")){
        tempGroup = new ArrayList<Question>();
        for(int i=0;i<temp.size();i++)
            if(temp.get(i).getCategory().equals(category))
                tempGroup.add(temp.get(i));
        getQuestionsForSelectedGroup(tempGroup, 10, 30);
    }
}
```

And here is what I try to do:

```
barProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    barProgressDialog.setTitle("Preparing Test");
    barProgressDialog.setMessage("Preparing Test");
    barProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(barProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    barProgressDialog.setProgress(0);
    barProgressDialog.setMax(100);
    barProgressDialog.show();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                getQuestionsForSelectedCategory();
                while (barProgressDialog.getProgress() <= barProgressDialog.getMax()) {
                    updateBarHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            barProgressDialog.incrementProgressBy(2);
                          }
                      });
                    if (barProgressDialog.getProgress() == barProgressDialog.getMax()) {
                        barProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

For the current code the progress bar fills up to 100 but it does nothing.

Comment: A kind of minimalistic approach could be to use the context.setProgressBarIndeterminate(true); when you start the long running method, and then set it to false at the end. 
Alternitively there are lots of libraries on github that will give you progress bars, otherwise you could look at clip images to make one or an animation that repeats infinitely until it's finished.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an AsyncTask to achieve this, whilst publishing your progress during the task.

```
AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>() {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        getQuestionsForSelectedCategory();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        barProgressDialog.setProgress(values[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        barProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}

task.execute();
```

Ensure your `getQuestionsForSelectedCategory` and `getQuestionsForSelectedGroup` methods are inside the AsyncTask and within the loops you can call `publishProgress(int progress)` to update the progress dialog.